# Can I embed an acinonyx plot into gWidgets (gWidgetsRGTK2 or gWidgetsQt) in R?

Tags: r, user-interface, gwidgets

I am trying to create a simple data viewing gui for neurophysiological recordings from EEG or MEG using R in which one could select any time point in the recorded timeseries and see the corresponding interpolated scalp distribution of the data.

What this means is that I have two graphs that need to be constantly updated on the basis of user input and I find R's regular graphs to be too slow for this task. I have recently found the [acinonyx](http://rforge.net/Acinonyx/index.html) graphics device which is indeed much faster than R's regular one, but I have not been able to embed graphs made by this device in a gui using gWidgets, nor could I find any documentation on how to embed it in a gui using other packages.

Is this possible at all? If not, what are the options for faster graphic devices in R that can be embedded into a gui?